# Python for loop multiplying by consecutive data frame column values

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, multiplication

Say I have a variable x = 100. I want to multiply it by the first value in a data frame column and then that number by the next value in the column until the end.

```
x*df['col1'][0]*df['col1'][1]*df['col1'][len(df)+1]
```

How can I achieve this in a for loop?

Comment: You are looking for a single value?  Or do you want to multiply each value in the column by value x?

Comment: @Chris A single value. I just edited the question so that there's no ambiguity

Comment: `x * df['col1'].prod()`?

Comment: @АлексейР seems like it works.